How to indent items inside a `tikzpicture` and `minipage` package?
I have a tikzpicture and minipage environment below, and I would like there to be a slight indent in the sub-categories a, b, c, etc. For example below: a. Sub-second \\ and a. again sub. How can I do this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\title{130 Cheat Sheet}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\advance\topmargin-.8in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
%\colorbox[HTML]{e4e4e4}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{texto}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\huge{\textbf{Title}}}\\
\end{center}
\begin{multicols*}{3}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries]

%------------ ODE Content ---------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \small{
        \begin{tabular}{lp{6cm} l}
        \textit{Title1} &  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        1. $B$ \\    
        2. Second  \\
        a. Sub-second \\
    3. Third \\
        \end{minipage} \\ \hline
    \textit{Titl2} &\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        1. here
        a. again sub
        \end{minipage} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{minipage}
};
%------------ ODE Header ---------------------
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {ODE};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{multicols*}


Unrelated to your question, but \tikzstyle is obsolete.

Your code does not compile.

Wouldn't it be easier to use a tcolorbox?

Aside from using tcolorbox, it would be preferable to use enumerate rather than hard-coding item labels. Maybe something like this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newlist{blist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[blist,1]{label=\arabic*.,wide,leftmargin=1em}
\setlist[blist,2]{label=\alph*.,leftmargin=1em}
\setlist[blist]{nosep}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\arraybackslash}X<{\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  [%
    enhanced,
    width=.5\textwidth,
    title=ODE,  
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    boxrule=1.2pt,
    boxsep=10pt,
    toptitle=0pt,
    bottomtitle=0pt,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    attach boxed title to top text left,
    halign title=left,
    colbacktitle=black,
  ]
  \small
  \begin{tabularx}\linewidth{lP}
    \textit{Title1} &  \begin{blist}
      \item $B$ 
      \item Second  
      \begin{blist}
        \item Sub-second 
      \end{blist}
      \item Third 
        \end{blist} \\ \midrule
    \textit{Titl2} &\begin{blist}
      \item here
      \begin{blist}
        \item again sub
      \end{blist}
    \end{blist} \\ \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

Poor-quality image of output:

I do wonder if you really need this many layers of formatting i.e. sub-lists within lists within tabulars within boxes! However, only you (and your readers) can know the answer to that question.
